# How to add an audit log for role added, removed, and username changed in Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

For my Discord.js bot, I am attempting to create an audit log that sends messages to a specific log channel within every server it is in for user changes. I have a working 'message deleted' audit log function, but when I attempt to carry it over to role adding and deletion, usernames, nicknames, and avatar changes, the bot fails to log this and crashes. How do I fix this issue within my code?

I have included both the message delete audit log message send, and the role add/remove/username change

```
client.on('messageDelete', function (message) {
  if (message.channel.type === 'text') {
    // post in the server's log channel, by finding the accuratebotlog channel (SERVER ADMINS **MUST** CREATE THIS CHANNEL ON THEIR OWN, IF THEY WANT A LOG)
    var log = message.guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL)
    if (log != null) {
      log.sendMessage('**Message Deleted** ' + message.author + '\'s message: ' + message.cleanContent + ' has been deleted.')
    }
  }
})

// sends message when important (externally editable) user statuses change (for example nickname)
// user in a guild has been updated
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', function (guild, oldMember, newMember) {
  // declare changes
  var Changes = {
    unknown: 0,
    addedRole: 1,
    removedRole: 2,
    username: 3,
    nickname: 4,
    avatar: 5
  }
  var change = Changes.unknown

  // check if roles were removed
  var removedRole = ''
  oldMember.roles.every(function (value) {
    if (newMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
      change = Changes.removedRole
      removedRole = value.name
    }
  })

  // check if roles were added
  var addedRole = ''
  newMember.roles.every(function (value) {
    if (oldMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
      change = Changes.addedRole
      addedRole = value.name
    }
  })

  // check if username changed
  if (newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username) {
    change = Changes.username
  }
  // check if nickname changed
  if (newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname) {
    change = Changes.nickname
  }
  // check if avatar changed
  if (newMember.user.avatarURL != oldMember.user.avatarURL) {
    change = Changes.avatar
  }
  // post in the guild's log channel
  var log = guild.channels.find('name', CHANNEL)
  if (log != null) {
    switch (change) {
      case Changes.unknown:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Update]** ' + newMember)
        break
      case Changes.addedRole:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Role Added]** ' + newMember + ': ' + addedRole)
        break
      case Changes.removedRole:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Role Removed]** ' + newMember + ': ' + removedRole)
        break
      case Changes.username:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
          oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
          newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator)
        break
      case Changes.nickname:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
          (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
            +newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
          (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'))
        break
      case Changes.avatar:
        log.sendMessage('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember)
        break
    }
  }
})
```

I expected the bot to send a message to my channel saying 'User Role Removed: memberName + their old role', and vise versa for role adding, but my bot fails to send these messages to the bot log channel I had set up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's the error when the bot crashes?

Comment: I am hosting my bot on Heroku, so I don’t know where to see the crash error message.

Comment: Check the command line. I'm not very familiar with Heroku but you should have some sort of console available.

Comment: @slothiful TypeError: "Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined" in multiple sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `guild` parameter in a `GuildMemberUpdate` event. Therefore, `newMember` is undefined because only two parameters are passed.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const guild = newMember.guild;

  // continue with code
});
```